# select top value samples using tf.gather for linear model results 'No gradients provided for any variable' error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I would like do following steps for a trainning:

1. create a tensor for linear: target=Weight * X
2. select top target values and drop all the rest samples.
3. get corresponding labels, which is Y.
4. use GradientDescentOptimizer, minimize sum(Y) and get fitted variable(W)

code

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
X=tf.placeholder(shape=[None,2], dtype=tf.float32)
Y=tf.placeholder(shape=[None,1], dtype=tf.float32)
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[2, 1]), dtype=tf.float32)

target=tf.matmul(X, W)

flattened=tf.reshape(target,[-1])
selected_targets, keys=tf.nn.top_k(flattened, k=100)

#get corresponding Y
selected_y = tf.gather(Y, keys)

#now we have top 100 selected_targets, and selected_y, train and evaluate W, and fit minimal sum(Y)
train_target = tf.reduce_sum(selected_y) #But if use selected_targets instead of selected_y, it would run successfully, why?
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1)
train = optimizer.minimize(train_target)

# training
x_vals = np.random.rand(1000,2)
y_vals = np.random.rand(1000,1)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(train, {X: x_vals, Y:y_vals})
print(sess.run([W]))
```

I got this error:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph
>   for ops that do not support gradients, between variables
>   [""] and loss
>   Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).

Anyone could help on this issue? I found it happens when applying `tf.nn.top_k` on tensors. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says this because there are no gradients. The graph you create is not differentiable, because the keys are the only thing connecting the loss to the W variable and the keys are non-differentiable integers.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your loss function is just not differentiable. You can use algorithms which work for non-differentiable functions such as REINFORCE or evolutionary strategies, or you can switch your loss function.